# No permission to use tabs.getSelected

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm learning how to make a chrome extension , right now all i'm doing is getting the url from the tab when you click on a button, but i get the following error

> Uncaught Error: You do not have permission to use 'tabs.getSelected'. Be sure to declare in your manifest what permissions you need.

Here is my manifest

```
{
"name": "test",
"version": "0.1",
"description": "share a link",
"browser_action": {
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_title": "test", 
"permissions": [
"tabs",
"http://*/*",
"https://*/*"
],
"popup": "popup.html"
}
}
```

and the code i'm running

```
$(document).ready(function(){
function myFunction(tablink) {
    alert(tablink);
}

$("#send").click(function()
{
    console.log("tablink");
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    myFunction(tab.url);
    });

});

});
```

Any suggestions on what i'm missing ?

Answer (score -1):

Is your code in a content script? While background pages, browser actions, and the like will receive the permissions declared in the manifests, content scripts largely do not.